# AutoMapper Map derived classes to property of base type collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to map two different objects to objects that are derived from an interface. Additionally, I need to have another property mapped to the derived types from the dtos. Given this object structure:

```
public interface ICoverage
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageA : ICoverage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Current { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageB : ICoverage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public bool HasRecord { get; set; }
}

public class Application
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public List<ICoverage> Coverages { get; set; }

    public Application()
    {
        Coverages = new List<ICoverage>();
    }
}

public class StagingDto
{
    public string Referrer { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public CoverageADto CoverageA { get; set; }
    public CoverageBDto CoverageB { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageADto
{
    public string Current { get; set; }
}

public class CoverageBDto
{
    public bool HasRecord { get; set; }
}
```

This mapping below works but I am wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
         cfg.CreateMap<StagingDto, Application>()
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Coverages.Add(new CoverageB()
            {
                HasRecord = src.CoverageB.HasRecord,
                Code = src.Code
            }))
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.Coverages.Add(new CoverageA()
            {
                Current = src.CoverageA.Current,
                Code = src.Code
            }));
```

Ideally I'd like to stay away from having to create any extension method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks a bit better:

```
cfg.CreateMap<StagingDto, Application>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Coverages,
        opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => new ICoverage[]
        {
            new CoverageA
            {
                Current = src.CoverageA.Current,
                Code = src.Code
            },
            new CoverageB
            {
                HasRecord = src.CoverageB.HasRecord,
                Code = src.Code
            }
        }));
```

Comment: This was an alternative that I stumbled upon as well, I used a List instead of array. I agree it looks better. Thanks for taking a look at this!